# Unable to play audio and video files

Tags: video, codecs

I am new to Linux and installed Ubuntu 12.10. It is showing some codecs or plugins are missing in the player

Comment: Did you already install Restricted Extras? sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras, give this a try and/or inform. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can Install VLC player from the Software Center, it plays virtually anything.